# Squatting a day after Deadlift

Tags: weightlifting, squats, deadlifts, splits

In my Push Pull Leg Split, I'll be doing Deadlift on Pull day and next day, i.e leg day, I'll be doing Squats. Is there any problem doing this? Will you get any injury due to both have a great presure on your spine and enough recovery time is not given?

Comment: Good programs have recovery periods baked in. If this is your first ~12 months of strength training you can get away with back-to-back days. But once you hit intermediate you'll need a day off in between big compound lifts for rest.

Comment: Yes, I just hit 6 months.

Comment: It passes the smell test then. Also, good work on following a compound program and not just curling in front of the mirrors like 80% of  folks in the gym.

Comment: Properly done squats mildly stress the lower back because of support given, but if it's giving your lower back an actual workout, then your form needs to be reviewed.  Make sure you aren't adding weight for the sake of ego, and use an amount of weight where you can keep proper form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your goals, your deadlift style, and your intensity - and intensity is driven by your goals. It is intensity that determines how you split your training up and how many rests days you need.

If you are deadlifting conventionally, this will probably work fine, assuming that your intensity is moderate to low. If you've only been training for 6 months then this is likely the case.

If your deadlifting sumo style, it would have a greater impact on your performance in the squat the next day, but you certainly are not going to hurt yourself if your are resting and eating enough and using proper form.

The only danger that would come into play here is if you made yourself so sore from deadlifts that your form broke down on squat day.

I don't know what your goals are, so beyond this it's hard to advise. Personally I always deadlift after squatting because for many people, myself included, squatting will increase your deadlift, but deadlift - conventional or otherwise - will do nearly nothing for your squat.

Thus I like performing the most efficient strength builder first, the squat, and then I hit deadlift with lighter weight and focus on strict form.

So no, there is nothing inherently wrong with this at all. Just be mindful that as the weights climb on the deadlift day, they will slow down and eventually stall out on squat day.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no obvious problem with squatting on the day after deadlifting.  Squatting and deadlifting during the *same workout* is fairly common, and fine.

Comment: Deadlifting then squatting is generally OK. I usually program squats before deadlifts, since squatting is a bit more technical and failing a squat is riskier than a deadlift.

Comment: It wont be a problem injury-wise, but I can see a problem as in you're legs will always be soar or tired from deadlifting the previous day, so you will never be able to hit legs as hard as you actually can when fully rested.